# Showing a function is in $ L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ a finite measure space and $g\in L^2_\mu$. Suppose there is a constant $K\ge 0$ s.t.
for any measurable   set $B$ , $|\left<g,\chi_B\right>|\le K \cdot \mu(B)$, how can I show that $g$ is in fact in $L^\infty_\mu$?

Comment: or put $f$ at the end

Answer (score 2):

Let $t > 0$ and define $B = \{g > t\}$.  Then you have
$$ t \mu(B) \le \int_B g \, d\mu \le K \mu(B)$$ which implies $\mu(B) = 0$ if $t > K$.

On the other hand if $t < 0$ you can define $B = \{g < t\}$ to find
$$-K \mu(B) \le \int_B g \, d\mu \le t \mu(B)$$
which implies $\mu(B) = 0$ if $t < -K$.

Thus $|g| \le K$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.